# How to use TailwindCSS3 with ngClass?

Tags: angular, tailwind-css, ng-class

I'm trying to use TailwindCSS in function inside ngClass.

TailwindCSS classes were generated in function to maintain my template but it doesn't work.

Please check my code below

*.component.html

```
...
<div class="grid grid-cols-12">
  <div ngClass="generateCol(fieldUI)">
...
```

*.component.ts

```
...
  generateCol(fieldUI: any) {
    return `col-span-12 sm:col-start-${fieldUI.startCol} sm:col-end-${fieldUI.endCol}`;
  }
...
```

Is it impossible with TailwindCSS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is possible to get it to work with ngClass and Tailwindcss v3.0.13 and Angular 13.1.3

This is my solution below:

*.component.html

```
<button [ngClass]="getValidateStyle()" 
  type="button" 
  (click)="buttonClicked($event)">
    <span class="px-2">{{text}}</span>
</button>
```

*.component.ts

```
  @Output() onClick = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Input() text: string|any;
  availableStyles: string[] = ['primary', 'secondary'];
  @Input() styleName!: string | "primary";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getValidateStyle(){
   if(this.availableStyles.includes(this.styleName))
   {
     return this.styleName;
   }   
   return "primary";
  }

  buttonClicked(event: any) {
    this.onClick.emit(event);
  }
```

*.component.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components{

    .primary{

        @apply px-2 flex rounded items-center text-sm bg-sky-100;
    }
}

@layer components{

    .secondary{

        @apply px-2 flex rounded items-center text-sm bg-sky-500;
    }
}
```

The usage of the button looks like this:

somefile.component.html

```
  <app-custom-button 
    styleName="secondary"
    text="This is a second button"
    (onClick)="logToConsole($event)">
  </app-custom-button>
```

somefile.component.ts

```
  logToConsole(event: any): void{
    console.log("Button clicked", event);
  }
```

Comment: I have one question for TailwindCSS v3. This is happening because of JIT?

Comment: @honeybear I don't think it is because of the JIT. I think it may have been because you could have missed square brackets [ ] around your ngClass. 

I am also not sure how you may have constructed your CSS file, so I provided as much as I could for you.

Answer (score 4):

Adding an answer here because this is the top result when looking this up. Tailwind now supports ngClass. Below is a quick example of a p tag that is invisible if there are no errors, and visible with red text if there are.

```
<p
    [ngClass]="{ 
      'visible text-red-600': fieldError(usernameContName, authForm, 'required'), 
      invisible: !fieldError(pwContName, authForm, 'required') 
    }">
    Username required.
</p>
```